# Powershell code to filter login/logout times (id 7001, 42)

Tags: powershell, authentication, time, tracking, logout

I am trying to create code in Powershell that will track the user login/logout times with the id codes of 7001 (login), and 42 (computer goes to sleep), and then export it as a csv.

My current problem is that sometimes the user will login/logout throughout the day, but I just want the earliest login and latest logout so I can track the total hours.

My current code works, but it gets every login/logout events of the day, seen below:

```bsh
   $startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

   $FileName = "Y:\Powershell_ " + $startDate.ToString('MMddyy') + ".csv" 

   $log_time = get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system';id='7001', '42'} 

   $log_time| Select Id, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated | export-csv $FileName
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-Eventlog` to make sure only events from the current day are retrieved. From there:

```
$Results =[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()

$Date = (get-date).Date 
$FirstLogin = Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 7001  -After $Date -Before $Date.AddDays(1) | Select -Last 1 
$LastLogout = Get-EventLog -LogName System -InstanceId 42 -After $Date -Before $Date.AddDays() -Newest 1

$Results.Add($FirstLogin)
$Results.Add($LastLogout)
$Results | Select Id, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated | export-csv -Path $Filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter by the day you working on first.

Since you can catch the output of a for each loop with a parameter, this is a way you can achieve your goal:

```bsh
   $startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-1).GetDateTimeFormats()[0]

   $FileName = "somepath.csv" 

   $log_time = get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system';id='7001', '42'} 

   $daily_events = foreach($event in $log_time)
   {
        if ($event.timecreated.GetDateTimeFormats()[0] -like "*$startDate*"){$event}
   }

   $daily_events | Select Id, MachineName, Message, TimeCreated | export-csv -Path $Filename
```

You can add this to track about the first and last while execution:

```bsh
   #The sort is by default from newer to older

   $first_event = $daily_events[-1].TimeCreated #last element of the array
   $last_event =  $daily_events[0].TimeCreated #first element of the array

   Write-Host "First event was $first_event in and the last event was in $last_event"
```

Comment: Glad i could help